# Function output with if-else statement

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement

Hello I have been study python for the pass few months and can't seem to figure out how to get the code below to work. The could runs but I am not receiving the output I was expected. I know strings are immutable, at first I kept using list function a realized that was incorrect but im stuck at thE moment. Not sure if I need to use a for loop to iterate through the string?

```
def function(input_string):
    output_string = ''
    if len(input_string)> 6:
       return input_string[1:] #Should return the string starting at index 1
    elif input_string.count('e') > 2:
       return input_string.count('e') #should return the count of 'E'
    elif input_string.isdigit():
       return input_string % 2  
#Should if string is a digit halve it example input_string = '4224' should be output_string'2114'
    else:
       return input_string[-1:0] #Should reverse the string outoutput_string='Ecetem'
            
    return output_string    

input_string = 'metecE'
output_string = function(input_string)
print(output_string)
```

I've tried using a for loop. This is a practice question for a test. The criteria after the # are required and it has to be in a function. I will not be allowed to change any of the code beside the logic I have with if-else statement. Any help with be greatly appreciate. I really want to figure out what I did incorrectly.

Comment: Reversing a string is done by `input_string[::-1]`.  If the start is less than the end, and you did not specify a negative increment, it will return an empty string.  When you do `input_string[-1:0]`, Python still wants to do forward indexing.  It doesn't try to "sort" the indexes.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I think i need to spend a little more time review string function.

Comment: Please describe which of the if-else options are not working and provide a relevant example.

Answer (score 1):

you had 3 mistakes:

1. you didn't convert the `input_string` to `int` when trying to divide it
2. you didn't use the right sign for `division` (`/` and not `%`)
3. you tried to `reverse` the `input_string` using `[-1:0]` when you need to do `[::-1]`

```
def function(input_string):
    if len(input_string) > 6:
        return input_string[1:]
    elif input_string.count('e') > 2:
        return input_string.count('e')
    elif input_string.isdigit():
        # you need to turn input_string to int and then use `/` to divide and not `%` 
        # (if the result to be int use `//`)
        return int(input_string) / 2
    else:
        # use [::-1] to reverse a string and not [-1:0]
        return input_string[::-1]


input_string = '4224'
output_string = function(input_string)
print(output_string)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot. I am trying to get more familiar with manipulating string. I did have one question, it was suppose to be stored in a empty string so output_string  was set to output_string = ' '. The function and the empty string was provide, and I was just suppose to provide the logic. Will this work having the empty string before my logic?

Comment: you can add `output_string = ""`, but you are not using the variable `output_string` in the function so no need for this declaration.

Comment: **unless you use `global` statement the variables inside a function and outside a function aren't shared**, you can have 2 variables with the same name and each of them will contain something different

Comment: And to extend that comment, **don't use `global` statements.**

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you guys so much for the  quick response. My headache is gone now lol.

Comment: Perhaps, instead of doing `return xxx`, you were supposed to do `output_string = xxx`, and then return `output_string` at the end.  In the code as you have it, every path through the `if` blocks will result in a `return`, so it never falls through.